# By-passable LNA getting damaged

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, lna

I am using [ATEK951P4](https://www.atekmidas.com/guide/EVB-ATEK951P4-01_UserGuide.pdf) in my design. As you know, this device can be switched between by-passable and LNA mode through control signal. The minimum required control voltage is 2V and maximum is 5V.

I am using the attached level translator circuitry for converting 1.8V signal to 3.3V signal and using it as control voltage for the LNA.

Both Level translator and by-passable LNA are two different boards.

We observed that, when the control is low, there is a resistance of 11.5ohm between control and ground. This is when the Level translator and by-passable LNA both are interfaced together.

The problem I am facing is:-

1. After testing the LNA for 100 times the LNA is getting damaged.
2. Before damage, the resistance between the control pin and ground is around some Kilo ohm. After the LNA gets damaged the resistance is 13.3 ohm.

[image]

Can somebody tell what might be the issue?

Comment: You need to cross reference the CTRL input in the data sheet schematic to where ever it connects in the 2nd schematic. Better to show one complete circuit so that all interfaces are understood. The power rails and rail voltages on both devices need to be shown to make any sense of this.

Comment: @Andyaka I have added single schematic snap

Comment: How many different devices have failed this way I.e. what are your statistics of OK versus not OK and, if it's just one item that has failed then, it's likely to be ESD. Stats please... how many have you built, how many have failed?

Comment: Any feedback on what I asked?